# MYSQL Updating multiple columns using variables

Tags: php, mysql, variables, multiple-columns, variable-assignment

I used this query to insert all my values into this database:

```
INSERT INTO products ($fields) VALUES ($values)
```

However, I try to use the same format for UPDATE:

```
UPDATE products SET ($fields) VALUES ($values) WHERE sku = '$checksku'
```

...and am getting thrown a syntax error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '('product,make,model,' at line 1
```

I can't figure it out.  Would appreciate any help.  Thanks.

Comment: The MySQL documentation is very useful: [UPDATE Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/update.html)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

UPDATE syntax is different than INSERT syntax. An example of UPDATE would be:

```
"UPDATE products SET field1 = 'value1', field2 = '$val2', field3 = 5 WHERE sku = '$checksku'"
```

Though this may be insecure. You should look into [parameterized queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4712037/what-is-parameterized-query).

Comment: I basically ended up using this, just disappointed that I had to do it 23 times (amount of fields)

Answer (score 2):

```
INSERT INTO products ($fields) VALUES ($values) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE field = VALUES(field), ...
```

Don't forgot about unique or primary key

Answer (score -5):

you need an =

```
UPDATE products SET ($fields) = $values WHERE sku = '$checksku'
```

Comment: This is not valid MySQL syntax.